# Event 153 Disk errors - Windows 10, WD Passport Drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

I'm having an issue whereas I have a USB 3.0 hub plugged into my USB 3.0 port on a Toshiba Satellite C-55a laptop.

I have a 2TB WD MyPassport USB3.0 drive plugged into the USB 3.0 Hub: (M drive)
I have a 4TB WD MyPassport USB3.0 drive plugged into the USB 3.0 Hub: (N drive)

When I write from M to N during a sync operation, I get the Event 153 Disk errors multiple times with different logical block addresses being listed:

The IO operation at logical block address 0xbda6520 for Disk 1 (PDO name: \Device\00000046) was retried.

Disk 1 in the error is the 4TB N Drive.

However, if I plug the 4TB N drive into a regular USB 2.0 port and run the same sync operation, no errors are listed.

Thus, I thought it might be an issue with the USB 3.0 Hub.  I replaced the hub with a new one and got the same behavior.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Are the drives powered through the USB 3 hub? If so, with both of them connected they may not be getting enough power.

Comment: Both drives were plugged into a non-powered USB 3.0 hub.  I went out and bought a powered one over the weekend.  That solved my problem. I'm no longer getting the Event 153 disk errors in the system log.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per a comment on my question, plugging both USB 3.0 drives into a POWERED USB 3.0 hub stopped me from getting the Event 153 disk errors.  Previously, both were plugged into a non-powered USB 3.0 drive.  I'm no longer getting the event 153 disk errors.